# MongoDB GeoNear - ReferenceError: message is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

This error is thrown with the following code. It was previously working but now is not.

```
var params;

params = {
  geoNear: 'locations',
  near: [coords.longitude, coords.latitude],
  spherical: true,
  distanceMultiplier: 6378160.0
};

db.mongo.command(params, function(err, near) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Any idea what could be causing this error?

Comment: It's probably an internal issue of the MongoDB driver or DAO you are using. There is no mention of the variable `message` in your code.

Comment: Yes, I don't use any variables called "message".

Comment: Well, what driver are you using? Have you considered filing an issue in its repository? (Github?)

Comment: It's the mongo-node-native driver, yes I have but the issue just started coming up. I also use MongoHQ so that might not be the problem. Just wanted to try to find out quick if it was somthing I was doing.

Comment: I updated my driver and it seems to have solved the problem, thanks for sending me down that path

Comment: Great ;-) Upgrading often solves a lot of minor problems.